# Implementing Click Action for AdChoice Icon in Native AdMob Banner with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently working on implementing a Native AdMob banner using Jetpack Compose. As per AdMob guidelines, native ads must include an Ad tag and an AdChoice icon.

I've set up the layout correctly with both of these elements, but I'm unsure about what the behavior should be when the AdChoice icon is clicked. Specifically, I need to know what code should be included in the adChoiceClick function.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AdAttributions(adChoiceClick:() -> Unit) {
      Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(26.dp)
                .height(20.dp).padding(end = 6.dp)
                .clickable {
                   adChoiceClick()
                }

        ) {
            Icon(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ad_choise),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(20.dp)
                    .height(20.dp)
                    .padding(bottom = 4.dp),

                tint = Color(0xff00aecd),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
}

@Composable
fun AdItem(nativeAd: NativeAd, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    //other view for native ad
    AdAttributions(adChoiceClick = {
        //What should go here?
    })
}
```

What should the adChoiceClick function do when the AdChoice icon is clicked?

Additionally, I've come across some information suggesting that the AdChoice icon might be implemented automatically. However, I'm unsure whether this holds true when using Jetpack Compose. Does anyone know if this is the case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!